# Error SQLCODE=-789, SQLSTATE=429BB using the function ST_Contains

Tags: database, db2, spatial, db2-luw

I'm getting the error

> The data type for parameter or SQL variable "SHAPE" is not supported in the  routine, compound SQL statement, or parameter list of a cursor value constructor.. SQLCODE=-789, SQLSTATE=429BB, DRIVER=4.18.60

When I use the code

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER z
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON x 
REFERENCING NEW AS N
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE contador INTEGER;

    SET contador = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM y s
    WHERE NOT(n.yID = s.yID AND db2gse.ST_Contains(s.shape, n.shape) = 1));
    IF contador > 0 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '20001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT ='invalid relationship';
    END IF;                              
END@
```

But if take out the function ST_Contains, it's works, I don't have a clue why that happens.

EDIT: Windows 7 64bit Ultimate with DB2 11.1 Server edition with ibm data studio, sorry I forgot about this detail.

Comment: What is the DB2 server version and operating-system platform ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error message does give you a clue: structured types (which ST_Geometry and its children are) are not supported in compound SQL statements, such as your trigger body. You'll need to do this check before you convert data from the exchange format to geometry or store the exchange format in the table along with geometry.

In the latter case you would have, along with the `shape ST_Geometry` column another one, e.g. `shape_wkt varchar(5000)` and in the trigger do type conversion on the fly:

```
...AND db2gse.ST_Contains(
    db2gse.ST_Geometry(s.shape_wkt), 
    db2gse.ST_Geometry(n.shape_wkt)
)
```

`db2gse.ST_Geometry(s.shape_wkt)` might be optional, because the value does not need to be instantiated in the trigger, so this might work:

```
...AND db2gse.ST_Contains(
    s.shape, 
    db2gse.ST_Geometry(n.shape_wkt)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, now I can see that the problem is with the n.shape, when I put  AND db2gse.ST_Contains(
    s.shape, 
    s.shape); Everythings goes alright, but when I use AND db2gse.ST_Contains(
    s.shape, 
    db2gse.ST_Geometry(n.shape_wkt)
) I still got the same error, what sould I do? sorry if the answer is obvious, I'm new in DB2

Comment: Just to confirm, your `n.shape_wkt` is of some basic SQL data type, such as VARCHAR? If it still refuses to compile like that, I guess your only option would be to handle this outside the database, like before inserting/updating the value. Sorry, I'm afraid I can't be of much help as I don't work with spatial data much.

Comment: Thanks for the help, The datatype is a db2gse.ST_Polygon

Comment: Well, then please re-read my suggestion -- you need to store both ST_Polygon and _its textual representation as VARCHAR_, and use the latter in the trigger so as not to expose ST_Polygon in the trigger body.